# Curl / dynamic verb (curb gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl

Given the following :

```
Curl.post(…)
Curl.get(…)
Curl.put(…)
Curl.delete(…)
```

I'm having a bunch of headers, so specifying those all over the place tends to make the code quite verbose in the end. A shared method like the following would be super useful :

```
   def query(verb, endpoint, params)
      Curl.send(verb, endpoint, params) { etc … }
   end
```

But currently getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):5
        1: from app/lib/query.rb:12:in `run'
NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass)
```

Obviously a syntax problem. Can it be done somehow ? Should another library be used for such need ?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question with the use of `send`. It's not clear what you're asking here?

Comment: because it does not work as shown and i can't find the correct syntax

Comment: Oh ok. It wasn't clear your query method is failing. Please show the call you're making and the error message.

Comment: ok thx, added the returned error

Comment: My problem is, I had done the send one, just found out where it had used it, and it should work. on rails 5.2, for some reasons, it's not :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so just found out, `params` can't be nil with such syntax; so a default empty hash is to be passed:

```
def query(token, verb, endpoint, params = {})
  http = Curl.send(verb, endpoint, params) do |http|
    http.headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip,deflate'
    http.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{token}"
  end
  http.body_str
end
```

Now :

```
ClassName.query('xxx', 'get', 'http://...')
ClassName.query('xxx', 'post', 'http://...', {some: :data})
ClassName.query('xxx', 'put', 'http://...', {some: :data})
ClassName.query('xxx', 'delete', 'http://...')
```

Works